# Разбиение строчного значения на токены по нескольким разделителям в цикле

Tags: sql, строки, парсер, oracle, plsql

Есть переменная с типом данных `nvarchar(max)` содержащая текст:

```
номер1;текст1/nномер2;текст2/nномерN;текстN/n
```

Нужно в цикле заполнять переменные значениями `номер1`,`текст1`, затем `номер2`, `тескт2` и т.д., чтобы в в каждой итерации цикла передавать их в функцию.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: @Akina вы теги видели - мне для PL\SQL

Comment: Ну развлекайтесь строковыми функциями в CTE - откусывайте с помощью SUBSTR() по одному значению.

Comment: @Akina можно пример?

Comment: А как должен конечный результат выглядеть?   
_Нужно в цикле скопировать_ - куда скопировать? _в этом же цикле их запихнуть в функцию_ - в каком цикле и в какую функцию?

Comment: @0xdb Нужно в цикле заполнять переменные nomer: integer и text: nvarcar2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рабочее решение на чистом PL/SQL:

```sql
declare
    str varchar2 (32000) := 'номер1;текст1/nномер2;текст2/n';
    pattern constant varchar2 (64) := '(\w+);(\w+)/n';
    type pairRow is record (num varchar2 (16), txt varchar2 (16));
    pair pairRow;
    counter int := 0;
    function print (pair pairRow) return varchar2 is begin 
        return 'pair('||pair.num||','||pair.txt||')';
    end; 
begin
    <<split>> loop counter := counter+1;
        exit split when regexp_substr (str, pattern, 1, counter) is null;
        pair.num := regexp_substr (str, pattern, 1, counter, null, 1);
        pair.txt := regexp_substr (str, pattern, 1, counter, null, 2);
        dbms_output.put_line (print (pair));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
pair(номер1,текст1)  
pair(номер2,текст2)
```

---

Можно заменить `REGEX_SUBSTR` на низкоуровневые SQl функции `SUBSTR,INSTR`, если обьём данных очень большой и важна производительность.
В любом случае, надо реализовать как функцию, чтобы вызов выглядел как-то так:

```
myFunc (getPair (str, counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Схематично:

```
WITH cte (one_fragment, slack)
AS ( SELECT SUBSTR(field, 1, INSTR(field || '\n', '\n') - 1) AS one_fragment,
            SUBSTR(field, INSTR(field || '\n', '\n') + 2, LENGTH(field)) AS slack
     FROM sourcetable
   UNION ALL
     SELECT SUBSTR(slack, 1, INSTR(slack || '\n', '\n') - 1),
            SUBSTR(slack, INSTR(slack || '\n', '\n') + 2, LENGTH(slack))
     FROM cte
     WHERE slack IS NOT NULL )
SELECT one_fragment
FROM cte;
```

---

Или что-то типа

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(field,'\n', 1, level) 
FROM sourcetable
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '\n', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```